# Web, Silverlight. Always show save file dialog when user try to download file

Tags: silverlight

I have link to file (Inside sharepoint list) I need always to show Save file dialog. 
But some browsers starts to download file without promt.
What should be done to avoid automatic download?

Comment: If you're already sending `Content-Disposition: attachment`, this is a browser-specific, user-configurable setting.

Comment: I have just link to file and nothing else, and silverlight client application. Content-Disposition: attachment - What is this?

Comment: http://pagebrooks.com/archive/2008/07/16/save-file-dialog-in-silverlight.aspx